# Excluding statistic using Data Pump API

Tags: oracle, datapump

How to exclude all statistics while exporting data using Oracle Data Pump API (DBMS_DATAPUMP package)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in [OTN Discussion Forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2422268&tstart=0)

```
dbms_datapump.METADATA_FILTER(
  handle = your_handle_here,
  name = 'EXCLUDE_PATH_LIST',
  value = 'STATISTICS'
);
```